# Android-WebView scrollable DIV does not show scrollbar

Tags: android, html, webview, scrollbar

I have a strange issue with Android webview.

I have a vertically overflowing DIV which is positioned fixed. It is fully scrollable but no scrollbar is visible.

This is *not* the bug of the early Android versions where DIV-scrolling didn't work at all.

Some cobbled-together-barebone HTML that suffers this issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {padding-left:200px;}
        body > div {position:fixed;left:0px;top:0px;bottom:0px;width:200px;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:auto;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="bla"></div>
    <p id="blubb"></p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam";
        window.onload = function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) text = text + text;
            document.getElementById("bla").innerHTML = "<b>There is a mystery inside me: I'm scrollable but no one will know....</b><br/>"+text;
            document.getElementById("blubb").innerHTML = "<b>This is body scroll... no problem here!</b><br/>"+text;
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The WebView part of the Layout:

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</WebView>
```

In onCreate():

```
webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView.loadUrl("the-html-from-above.html");
```

In Google Chrome, the scrollbars work as expected, but in my WebView, the scrollbar and the overscroll indicator flashing of the DIV is missing but I can scroll it.

Something is wrong with my WebView. It happens through all versions of Android from 5.0 to 8.0.

In the real thing I'm working on, HTML, CSS and JS are actually split up to separate files. I just put it together to get a smaller example for this posting. So that is not the cause of that. Furthermore, the original thing does not have JavaScript used/turned on. I used it here to fill the DIV and the BODY with a huge text to make them overflowing.